# Adding a foreign key is not working in db browser for sqlite

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, syntax-error, db-browser-sqlite

`ALTER TABLE employee ADD FOREIGN KEY(branch_id) REFERENCES branch(branch_id) ON DELETE SET NULL;`

gives me following error message:

near "FOREIGN": syntax error
in line 12:
ALTER TABLE employee
ADD FOREIGN

The branch table exists with the branch_id column, also the employee table has the branch_id column, both with the same data types. Foreign Key is enabled in Pragma.

Here are the tables:

`CREATE TABLE employee ( emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY, branch_id INT ); CREATE TABLE branch ( branch_id INT PRIMARY KEY, branch_name VARCHAR(40), mgr_id INT, mgr_start_date DATE, FOREIGN KEY(mgr_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id) ON DELETE SET   NULL);`